# CSRF issue in react native and Django

Tags: reactjs, django, react-native

I recently updated by react native from 0.67.0 to 0.72.6 ,  django i'm still using 3.1.2.
For  session i'm using  the default what ever django provides.
Now i have a csrf token stored in Asynchronous storage in mobile apk previously, call this apk_1, this uses the old react native version i.e 0.67.0 ,
Now i provided a update on google play store with new react native 0.72.6, now after updating the app from playstore one of the post method is not working, this post method uses csrf token , it shows 403 forbidden,  how can the change in react native framework will affect this csrf token issue ?.

im using axios for sending requests, but i have not updated the axios package it is same as apk_1

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide code sample ? Or you can just exempt csrf on ulrs.py

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

...
path("api_path", csrf_exempt(YOURVIEWFUCTION)),
...
```

Comment: i can generate the new token from frontend and it will work fine  , i can also add csrf_exempt but what can cause this issue like im passing the same csrf but after updating the apk  it is causing  403

Comment: Did you remeber to add CORS in your settings